# Magento 2 - Undefined index: instance in PluginList/PluginList.php

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error while compilation.

```
Notice: Undefined index: instance in /var/www/html/magenot2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php on line 196
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: where you have used this "instance" variable?

Comment: @Nitz What is your Magento version? And what is your PHP version?

Comment: Magento - 2.1.8 and php 7.0

Comment: I am also stuck on same problem. Any solution or how debug this issue? plz help. @P_U

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to inject via constructor

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $objectManager
) {
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager::getInstance();
}
```

You should not use it via DI, use directly like static method.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
```

In general, you MUST avoid to use this construction in your code. Only for testing or fast solution to get any object.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this ERROR follow the below steps.

Basically, one of your modules causing the issue.

Goto : **vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList.php**

At line number 196 modify the function something like below.

private function trimInstanceStartingBackslash(&$plugins)
{

```
    foreach ($plugins as &$plugin) {
        if(isset($plugin['instance'])) {
            $plugin['instance'] = ltrim($plugin['instance'], '\\');
        }else
        {
            echo "not set";
            print_r($plugins);
        }
    }
}
```

Run **di:compile** and see which module has an issue.